# What is the difference between to notify something to someone and to notify someone of something

Tags: meaning, grammar

Many speakers find the construction 'to notify something to someone' incorrect (as opposed to to notify someone of something) - see for example http://www.proz.com/kudoz/English/general_conversation_greetings_letters/4167728-notify_to.html. Many dictionaries do not distinguish between the two (e.g. Macmillan, which gives both. The OED on-line distinguishes, without comment, between to 'Inform (someone) of something, typically in a formal or official manner' (= notify someone of something) and to 'Give notice of or report (something) formally or officially' (notify to). I would have flagged 'notify to' as wrong, but I am now confused.

Comment: I *report* something to someone, but I don't *notify* something to someone. American English speaker.

Comment: @δοῦλος I don't use the expression myself either. But Macmillan's research data outranks both of us.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth- I am not sure that it does outrank us. So far I have not found anybody who approves 'notify to'. My feeling is that it may have a residual use = to serve a writ ...

Comment: There are 100 000+ Google hits for "notify it to", including on the first page the non-legalese '... so that their computer systems automatically recognise a diagnosis of a notifiable disease, and automatically notify it to the proper officer.' ODO and Macmillan license it. People at your first linked website sanction it. 'Me and mi mates' is an unacceptable sample.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. You are quite right that me 'n me mates is not quite scientific (although 'me mates' in this case is the combined translation resources of the European Union). However, google is also a resource that needs to be taken with kid gloves. The certainty with which language professionals say that it is wrong should also not be ignored, and there must be something behind it. The problem is, what?

Comment: In this connection, can anybody comment on the distinction in meaning raised by the OED?

Comment: You mean ODO. OED is a far weightier authority. I'm sure they will give examples of the notify something to someone usage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21703/discussion-between-jeremy-gardner-and-edwin-ashworth).

Answer (score 3):

***Something to someone***

One could *indicate, explain, point out*, etc. *Notify* sounds borderline. I'm not sure I would *notify something to...*

***Someone of something***

Here one can *notify, inform, tell, warn, etc* But I wouldn't use *indicate, explain or point out*

Comment: I'm not going to use the 'notify X to Y' version in a hurry myself, either. But one can't just ignore the corpus data doubtless backing Macmillan's licensing of the usage. Once we start ranking opinion above the findings of genuine research we should really question our principles.

Comment: I'm not necessarily ranking my own usage above the findings of research. I'm simply saying what sounds idiomatic to me. But note that I did think *notify to* was a borderline case. One does hear it used, and I may even have used it myself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I don't ever recall hearing anyone use the "notify something to someone" form.  It may be in the book, but it's far from normal usage.

Comment: @Hot Licks 'I've never heard it, so...' appears far too often on ELU. The dictionary compilers make sure they consider far more material and in far more registers than any single person could be expected to. 'I've never heard it, but ...' is far more acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The Macmillan is not alone. I have looked up "Notify" in the Oxford Living Dictionary and found:
"Give notice of or report (something) formally or officially.
‘births and deaths are required by law to be notified to the Registrar’"
So, it must be acceptable.