# To notify someone upon something

Tags: verbs, prepositions

When telling someone that you are going to notify him as soon as something has expired, is it grammatically accurate to say

"I'll notify you upon expiry"

or should I use "notify of" as per [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231861/what-is-the-difference-between-to-notify-something-to-someone-and-to-notify-some)

Answer (score 3):

I think either is acceptable. "upon" is normally used when you notify someone as or immediately after the action, while "of" can often be a warning that something is about to happen.