# "notify" in passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

I have a question about the word "notify" when it is used in the passive voice.
Please see the examples below:

*1) We will be notified of subsequent updates.*

*2-1) Subsequent updates will be notified of.*

*2-2) Subsequent updates will be notified.*

Sentence 1 is perhaps the basic passive form of "notify".
However, when it comes to the form of sentences 2, it's quite confusing.

Although I think the word is supposed to be used like (2-1),
any occurrences found in google have the form of (2-2).

Can anybody tell me why? Actually, "updates" are not persons who are informed but things to be reported.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between to notify something to someone and to notify someone of something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231861/what-is-the-difference-between-to-notify-something-to-someone-and-to-notify-some)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, (2-1) is simply **wrong.** There is no way that that can be parsed as grammatical. So I'm going to discount that and simply have examples (1) and (2), which you've numbered (2-2).

Your other examples might be better expressed as

> 1. You will be notified of subsequent updates
> 2. Subsequent updates will be notified to you.

Both are licensed:

> Inform (someone) of something, typically in a formal or official manner.
>   *‘you will be notified of our decision as soon as possible’*
>
> Give notice of or report (something) formally or officially.
>   *‘births and deaths are required by law to be notified to the Registrar’*
>
> — [Oxford via Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/notify)

The active forms of your examples are

1. [We] will notify you of subsequent updates
2. [We] will notify subsequent updates to you.

Thus the object of *notify* (the patient in passive forms) can be either the recipient **or** the notification itself.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see how it works perfectly!